# Saving a DICOM file in another format to a specified location in disk - MFC

Tags: mfc, save, jpeg, dicom

I am using **CxImgDCM**, a class derived from CxImage to handle DICOM files. I need to save a  DICOM image in another format like **JPEG**, **TIFF** and so on. These functions exist in the CxImgDCM class, but I need to save it in a desired location using the CFileDialog class. I have got the file format and have opened the Save As Dialog. What do I do inside the **IDOK** condition to save my image in a preferred location. The code is as follows :-

```
if(dlg.m_FileType == 0)
{   
            // Save as JPEG File
    CString strFilter = "*.jpg";
    CFileDialog FileDlg(FALSE, CString("*.jpg"), NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY |  OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, CString(strFilter));

    if (FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)  
    {  
                    // What should I do here? 
                    // There is a Save_DCM_as_JPG("filePath") function. 
                    // But how do I select the location to save it and write the file there?
    }
}
```

NOTE : The "filePath" argument is the source, not destination.

Answer (score 0):

```
Save_DCM_as_JPG(FileDlg.GetPathName());
```

Comment: The original image is the argument/input to Save_DCM_as_JPG. That file will be converted to JPG, as in... Save_DCM_as_JPG("original image file"). I want to know how to give the **destination** to save it.